# Flutter scrolling behavoir

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I've searching for a solution for this:
I have a headline in my view and I want to show the headline only on top, when I'm scrolling down. This is my current example:
[image]

So the blue headline should only appear if I'm scrolling down. Do you have any ideas, how to do this?

Thanks,
Sir!

Comment: You need to use sliverAppBars. You can find a quick intro here https://youtu.be/R9C5KMJKluE

Answer (score 1):

You can use this approach:

Define global variable called `isScrollingDown`.

Create a function that checks whether the user scrolling down or up.

```
  void checkScrollDirection() {
    if (scrollController.position.userScrollDirection == ScrollDirection.reverse) {
      isScrollingDown = true;
    } else {
      isScrollingDown = false;
    }
  }
```

Give this function to your scrollcontroller as a listener.

```
scrollController.addListener(checkScrollDirection);
```

After that manage visibility of AppBar with isScrollingDown condition. You can do with either Visibility widget or AnimatedContainer etc.